# How to Sign Android Phonegap App

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to sign my apk file I made using phonegap but I can't figure out how to do it. I can't find good, in-depth directions and I have little programming experience,

I have tried to open eclipse and import the application folder but when I choose it and click finish it doesn't respond!!

So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CalebB

**1.) Add Key/Signing**

sign in to phonegap, click on the top right corner icon and click "Edit Account". Next under the Signing Keys tab, click the "add a key" button, enter your title/alias, select the keystore file (the file location you marked down  and click submit key.

**2.) Unlocking your Key**

Next navigate to Account>Edit Account>Signing Keys Tab and click the lock icon. Supply the certificate password from step six and the keystore password from step 4 and click submit key.

**Now you got your app signed** and ready for market upload

Answer (score 2):

To Sign Your Android/Phonegap Application Follow the Steps Bellow:

**1.) Download and Install Java**

You can download and/or update your local java [Here.](http://www.java.com/en/download/)

**2.) Set Java_Home directory**

Instructions for setting Java_Home directory can be found [Here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

**3.) Run The Following Command In Command Prompt**

You can find your local command prompt either through searching from your start menu (vista and newer) or by opening "run" (Windows Key + R), enter "cmd" and press enter. Then Enter The Following Command:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore [**keystore_name**].keystore -alias [**alias_name**] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**4.) Enter/Confirm keystore password.**

Enter the keystore password and confirm. (Note the password may not visibly appear while typing into cmd.)

**5.) Enter some more information**

Follow keytool's instructions, entering needed information as prompted.

**6.) Enter Alias Password**

Keytool should then ask for the Alias password for your alias name. If it's different than the keystore password, enter and confirm. Otherwise press Return/Enter. (I would mark this password down as you will need it later on)

**7.) Confirm Location of Signing Key**

After this you should receive a signing key and bellow it will show where it is stored. Mark this location down for future reference.

**8.) Add Key/Signing**

Next sign in to phonegap, click on the top right corner icon and click "Edit Account". Next under the Signing Keys tab, click the "add a key" button, enter your title/alias, select the keystore file (the file location you marked down in step 7) and click submit key.

**9.) Unlocking your Key**

Next navigate to Account>Edit Account>Signing Keys Tab and click the lock icon. Supply the certificate password from step six and the keystore password from step 4 and click submit key.

**10.) Set Key as Default(Optional)**

You can then set your key as the default key either by using the checkbox in the keys list, or from within your application's details selecting the key you uploaded and unlocked.

**More Info**

You can also find more information [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) if you would like to dig deeper. Also this instruction is illustrated from the [Android Signing](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html) article which re-iterates the instructions above as well as providing more sources if you are still having issues.

Comment: @Smart Coder, Also a brief side note for future reference. This may possibly by a question more suited for stackexchance/[Super-User](http://superuser.com/) but it does have to do with software development in a form so I hope this helps.